# Laravel windows 8.1 Browser No Input File Specified

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, yaml, homestead

I have been trying to get laravel working for over a week now and have come close, but I am unable the project in my web browser. I receive the 'No input file specified" when I direct to 127.0.0.1:8000. I have tried every solution I have found on the web, but can not find a solution. I am using the latest version of vagrant, virtualbox, composer and homestead.

My Yaml is:

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel-basics/public
      hhvm: true

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Vagrant file is:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
end
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 80
end
```

Hosts File

```
    # Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 laravel.dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got port `8000` from.

This line:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 80
```

Says that, on your master machine (what you're reading this from), port `4567` will be forwarded to your guest machine's (the VM you spin up) port `80`.

However, this is not necessary to know. Apache and Nginx listen to port 80 by default, and all browsers us it when you visit a URL.

This means that this line in your `/etc/hosts` file,

```
127.0.0.1 laravel.dev
```

allows you go to go http://laravel.dev without anything further.

If this is still not working, you have a few options:

- Use `$ vagrant ssh` to go into the VM and read the Nginx logs. I believe they should be at `/var/logs/nginx/{vhost_name}`.
- I have an older, more mature, more powerful alternative to Homestead: https://puphpet.com. I've successfully spun up Laravel, SF2, ZF2 and countless other frameworks through this.